# ggiraph font size HTML

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-size, ggiraph

I am using ggiraph with geom_tile_interactive in RStudio. The graph renders beautifully in the viewer window but after converting to HTML & hovering over the graph online, the font size is too tiny to read. I am using ggiraph 0.8.7 and the latest CRAN version of htmlwidgets. This is my code

```
g <- ggplot(gg.dat, aes(x = class, y = var.lab, fill = probability,
                        tooltip = paste0(class, "\n", var.lab, "\n", probability),
                                       data_id = var.lab)) +
         geom_tile_interactive(width = .75)

    g.int <- girafe(ggobj = g)

    saveWidget(g.int, file = paste0(my.dir, "/", my.graph.name, ".html), 
               selfcontained = TRUE)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Don

Answer (score 0):

Whereas you can set the font size for the chart itself using `theme()` or `size=` as in `ggplot2` for the tooltip you have to set the font size using the `options=` argument of `girafe()`. To this end `ggiraph` provides a helper function `opts_tooltip()` which allows to style the tooltip via the `css=` argument, e.g. in the code below I have set the `font-size` to `4rem`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on mtcars:

```
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

gg.dat <- mtcars |>
  group_by(class = factor(cyl), var.lab = factor(am)) |>
  summarise(
    probability = mean(mpg),
    .groups = "drop"
  )

g <- ggplot(gg.dat, aes(
  x = class, y = var.lab, fill = probability,
  tooltip = paste0(class, "\n", var.lab, "\n", probability),
  data_id = var.lab
)) +
  geom_tile_interactive(width = .75) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

g.int <- girafe(
  ggobj = g,
  options = list(
    opts_tooltip(
      use_fill = TRUE,
      css = "padding:5pt;font-size:4rem;color:white"
    )
  )
)

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(g.int,
  file = "foo.html",
  selfcontained = TRUE
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Stefan. That does the trick and much appreciated. It seems unusual to me that the ggirafe graph named "g" above renders in the viewer fine without the need for a call to the options function as required for g.int to be readable as a HTML file. Thanks again.